# Removing values from a Java hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Lets say I do `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

`map.containsValue(value)` returns true whether or not the value is found in the hashmap. But I found that there is no way to remove a value. Like `map.removeValue(value)`. You can only remove the key, as in, `map.removeKey(key).`

Now, my question is, does removing the key also remove the value?

So when I search `map.containsValue(value)`, will it return false if I deleted the key associated with the value with `map.removeKey`?

Comment: Why don't you try? Also `removeKey` does not exists. And if you read the doc it states : _"Removes the mapping for a key from this map if it is present (optional operation)."_

Comment: What did you get from trying it?

Comment: Waste of time, its more helpful if you just give me the answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant remove.

Comment: You prefer wasting other people's time... Makes sense...

Comment: @assylias, saying yes or no doesn't take time at all, comparing to setting up code, and everything to test a simple thing.

Comment: It's not much code. Trying it would improve your knowledge. It's obvious that you don't like programming.

Comment: Testing it probably takes less time than writing your question...

Comment: @user2817240 You wasted more time for asking this question here than trying to test it yourself or reading the documentation.

Comment: lol fine, w/e I guess I'll try it. Didn't think a simple question would stir so much trouble. Simple question = simple answer.

Comment: And you don't know me enough to determine whether I like coding or not. Rude.

Comment: I don't like *wasting time* would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is, does removing the key also remove the value?

Yes.  Sort of.

Actually, it removes the *specific entry* that consists of the key and the value.

If the value is also used in another entry, then that other entry is unaffected, and the value will still show up in the `values` collection.

> So when I search `map.containsValue(value)`, will it return false if I deleted the key associated with the value with `map.removeKey`?

It depends ... see above.

---

This information can easily be found by *reading the javadoc* carefully.

(The problem with the "try it and see" approach is that it is easy to write a "black box" test that will cause you to drawing the wrong conclusions.  I would only suggest "try it and see" if the javadoc did NOT contain the information.  And I'd add "read the source" ... )

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer. Many of the other replies were telling me to "try it and see" but ya I"ll read the java doc.